# Cloudera Hadoop 500 Error

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I am using Cent os-6 and using cloudera cdh4.7. When I try to browse the file system from the browser using the proxt http://xxx.xxx.xxx:50070. I am getting the following error that is given below:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /nn_browsedfscontent.jsp. Reason: 
    Cannot issue delegation token. Name node is in safe mode.
 Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually.  NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode..
Caused by:
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot issue delegation token. Name node is in safe mode.
 Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually.  NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode..
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDelegationToken(FSNamesystem.java:5450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getDelegationToken(NameNodeRpcServer.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NamenodeJspHelper$1.run(NamenodeJspHelper.java:435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NamenodeJspHelper$1.run(NamenodeJspHelper.java:432)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NamenodeJspHelper.getDelegationToken(NamenodeJspHelper.java:431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NamenodeJspHelper.redirectToRandomDataNode(NamenodeJspHelper.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.nn_005fbrowsedfscontent_jsp._jspService(nn_005fbrowsedfscontent_jsp.java:70)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:1069)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I have used the statement given below to remove from the safemode:
"sudo -u hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave",by using this statement also there was no change.

Please help me in crossing this hurdle .

Comment: Check if your Namenode running out of main memory.

Comment: try restarting your namenode and other services. Then format namenode if possible try again

Answer (score 0):

Your Namenode is in save mode.

You need to leave that.

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Here is the [Explanation](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html)

Comment: After I have performed the following steps.1)Restarted the data node,name node,secondary name node. 2)Formatted the name node. 3)Started to run the hdfs for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done then ,I have given the statement as "sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp". I got the following error given below:"mkdir: Cannot create directory /tmp. Name node is in safe mode".

Comment: just do "hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave". No need to restart anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your storage is not full. Delete some files and make space. Otherwise the system will go to safemode again.